# Obfuscating sharepoint document URL

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does sharepoint have any mechanism to obfuscate the urls of the sharepoint documents? My custom application saves its documents in a sharepoint site and I would like to obfuscate the document url that is displayed in the custom application

Answer (score 1):

You can use enable and configure unique Document IDs to obfuscate the urls of the SharePoint documents. The url of document like this:

```
/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=5JSTYM4NXMKN-105322898-4
```

References:

[Enable and configure unique Document IDs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984)

[Activate and configure Document IDs in a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/activate-and-configure-document-ids-in-a-site-collection-66345c77-f079-4104-ac7a-e25826849306)